# Create a random number WITHIN a random range of numbers in JAVA

Tags: java, random

I have been given a task to create a truly random computer number guessing game generator.

So,

1. Create a minimum for the range(which is completely random)
2. Create a maximum ""       ""
3. create a number within the range.

My question is how do I make sure that randMIN is always LOWER than randMAX?  Those are the names of my random numbers for the border of the guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

This method will generate two numbers where the `randMIN` value is always lower than the `randMAX` value:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomMinMax
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        //Set range (minimum and maximum values).
        int min = 5;
        int max = 20;

        //Get a random value between the (min) and (max-1) values and assign it to randMIN.
        //In this example, randMIN will take any value between 5 and 19.
        int randMIN = min + random.nextInt(max - min);

        //The randMAX value will be a number generated between the (randMIN+1) and (max) values.
        //In this example, if randMIN is 14, then randMAX will take any value between 15 and 20.
        int randMAX = randMIN + 1 + random.nextInt(max - randMIN);

        //Print the results.
        System.out.println("randMIN: " + randMIN);
        System.out.println("randMAX: " + randMAX);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about generating two random numbers in that range.

After thats done, you check which one is bigger, and which one smaller.

like:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int randMin, randMax;

do {
    int a = rnd.nextInt(randMax - randMin + 1) + randMin;
    int b = rnd.nextInt(randMax - randMin + 1) + randMin;

    if (a < b) {
        randMin = a;
        randMax = b;
    } else if (a > b) {
        randMin = b;
        randMax = a;
    }
    // Repeat as long as there is no strict order
} while(randMin == randMax);
```

You could also check if both numbers have the same value and in that case regenerate those numbers.

I hope this could help you a little bit.